# How do I highlight selected lines in Emacs ?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I have tried searching this simple question in Google. But didn't get the correct answer in the first few pages.

What I want to do is very simple: in a source file, highlight 5th line, and 15th line, and 23th line for comparison.

I believe there should be a short-cut for it. Could anybody tell me ?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's possible but didn't find either. With [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) ? [video](http://emacsrocks.com/e13.html)

Comment: @Ehvince I once saw people did that with no extra packages.

Comment: You can highlight by regexp, https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/highlighting-by-word-line-regexp -- I guess hacking that to match line numbers instead should not be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just wanna compare code from different lines,`narrow-to-region` and `indirect-buffer` are your solution.Usage:[Narrow-to-region-indirect for Emacs](http://demonastery.org/2013/04/emacs-narrow-to-region-indirect/)